# How to merge two tables and order them based on the timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables as shown below

Table: behaviour

```
id - hash - page - timestamp
1 - abc - page 1 - 2016-06-06 13:20
2 - abc - page 2 - 2016-06-06 13:18
```

Table: behaviour_actions

```
id - hash - page - action - timestamp
1 - abc - page 1 - form - 2016-06-06 13:19
2 - abc - page 2 - form - 2016-06-06 13:12
```

A user (hash) has multiple entries in behaviour and multiple entries on behaviour_actions.
What i am trying to do is to join the two tables and order by timestamp.

So the end result will be a mix of the two tables, but in respect with time.

My query below does not sort them as I want, because it doesn't put each entry of the two tables below each other based on time. I am using PHP. what I can do about it?

```
SELECT behaviour.page, behaviour.timestamp, behaviour_actions.page, behaviour_actions.timestamp, behaviour_actions.action
FROM behaviour
join behaviour_actions on behaviour.hash = behaviour_actions.hash
WHERE behaviour.hash =  'abc'
```

[image]

Comment: To order you can use `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for that sample please?

Comment: @Mureinik i have added a screen of what I get

Comment: @Mureinik and added sample data too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be close to what you are asking for.

```
 SELECT 'ba' AS src
      , ba.page
      , ba.timestamp
      , ba.action
   FROM behaviour_actions ba
  WHERE ba.hash = 'abc'

  UNION ALL

 SELECT 'b' AS src
      , b.page
      , b.timestamp
      , NULL AS action
   FROM behaviour b
  WHERE b.hash = 'abc'
  ORDER BY 2
```

Note that to get the two queries to "line up" for the UNION ALL operation, we have to return the same number of columns. So we return a NULL value as a placeholder for the `action` column in the result. We could just as easily return an empty string,  `'' AS action` or any other expression. But we do need to return a fourth column, so that both queries return four columns.

If you want the row from `behaviour` listed first, if the timestamp values match...

```
  ORDER BY 2,1
```

If you always want the row from `behaviour` first,

```
  ORDER BY 1,2
```

It's not mandatory to return that first column, the discriminator column. But typically when I get a resultset like this, I also want to know which SELECT returned the row. In this example, the value `b` tells me it was a query of `behaviour` that returned the row. A value of `ba` tells me it was the query of `behaviour_actions` that returned the row.

Answer (score 0):

`join` combines tables rows' side by side. It sounds like you should be using the `union all` operator, to combine rows one after the other:

```
SELECT page, timestamp
FROM   behaviour
UNION ALL
SELECT page, timestamp
FROM   behaviour_actions
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Hi, i want the `action` to be included too on the results of the `behaviour_actions` table

Comment: We will typically include a discriminator column, so we can tell which SELECT returned a row... `SELECT 'b' AS src, page, ... UNION ALL SELECT 'ba' AS src, page, ... `

Comment: @spencer7593 can you share it to an answer please?